# jquery do an action for the first one of three objects with the same class names

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have 3 select option in my html page like this

```
    <select class="combo">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select class="combo">
        <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select class="combo">
       <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
    </select>
<br/>
<button type="submit" class="search_btn">
                                <img src="media/images/search_icon.png" title="Search" /></button>
                            <input type="text" lang="fa" id="search" name="search"/>
```

I want if the first select value  was NOT null, trigger an action. something like this.

```
if( $('.combo').has('option').length > 0 ) { 
 $('#search').val('');
}
```

The problem is that i don't know how to address this action for the first select and not the second and third (because they have same class names).

Note that i **don't** want to set ID to the first select in **code preview**

Comment: What do you mean by _select value was NOT null_?

Comment: @Vega: OOPS. i missed the first option of the select. I just edited the question. I mean when the option is anything except the first ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:first` selector:

```
if ( $('.combo:has(option):first').length > 0 ) { 
   $('#search').val('');
}
```

Note that `$('.combo:has(option):first')` differs from `$('.combo:first:has(option)')` the first one selects the first `select.combo` that has option element and the second one selects the first `select.combo` only *if* that has option element.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `:first()` selector jQuery offers (http://api.jquery.com/first/)

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first matching
>   element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AS8wA/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want.. but going to answer based on this...

> *I want if the first select value was NOT null, trigger an action*

and

> OOPS. i missed the first option of the select. I just edited the question. I mean when the option is anything except the first ""

**JS:**

```
if( $('.combo:first').val() == '') {  //assuming not NULL means select value
   $('#search').val('');
}
```

`:first` is used to select the 1st matched element from the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use :first selector in jQuery to retrieve the first option like this:

```
if ( $('.combo:has(option):first').length > 0 ) { 
   $('#search').val('');
}
```